# Spring MVC application that returns several records to View that displays one record at a time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pagination

I have a form that captures citizen information, so i have a class Citizens

**Citizens Class**

```
public class Citizens implements Serializable{

    private int socialSecurityNumber;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String oName;
    private String photo;
    private int countryId;
    private String addLn1;
    private String addLn2;
    private String addLn3;......
```

**DAO** class that returns a list/a single record of citizens based on the where_clause which can be any value or combination of values.

```
if(where_clause != null){
        //add WHERE to string
        where_clause = "WHERE " + where_clause;
        //get length of string 
        int where_clause_length = where_clause.length();
        //remove last 'and' from string
        where_clause = where_clause.substring(0, where_clause_length - 5);

        logger.info(where_clause);
    }       

    String sql = "SELECT socialSecurityNumber, fName, lName, oName, photo, countryId, addLn1, addLn2, addLn3," 
                +"genderId, ethnicityId, skinColorId, eyeColorId, hairColorId, occupationId, phoneNo, maritalStatusId," 
                +"noticableFeatures, weight, height, citizenTypeId, dob "
                +"FROM crimetrack.tblcitizens " + where_clause;

    logger.debug(sql);

    List<Citizens> listOfCitizens = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new CitizensMapper());     
    return listOfCitizens;
```

In the **Controller** this is what happens:

```
if (user_request.equals("Query")){
   logger.debug("about to preform query");
   if(citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen).isEmpty()){
      model.addAttribute("icon","ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close");
      model.addAttribute("results","Notice: Query Caused No Records To Be Retrived!");                           
 }

 model.addAllAttributes(citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen));

 return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");
 }                   
}
```

The problem here is this query returns 3 records but only the last record is displayed on the view. Under is what the jsp looks like, it uses spring form tags. What i want to do is add a next record button and when the user clicks next record i want to move to the next record in the List and display it to the user. How can this be achieved, if it cannot be done using this approach what is the best approach to do this. I was reading about **Pagination** however i am not sure how it can be implemented into this application. Can some one please assist me or guide me on how to approach this:

**Jsp**

```
<form:form id="citizenRegistration" name ="citizenRegistration" method="POST" commandName="citizens" action="citizen_registration.htm">
                    <div id="divRight" class="mainDiv">             
                        <div class="divGroup" id="divCharInfo"> 
                            <label id="status"></label>                             
                            <div id="camera"></div>             
                            <div><p><canvas id="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas><canvas id="canvas2" height="240" width="320"></canvas><form:errors path="photo" class="errors"/></div>
                                    <form:input path="photo" id="photo" type="hidden"/>
                                    <input  id="upload" type="button" value="Take Photo">
                                    <input  id="retake" type="button" value="Re-Take Photo">

                            <ol>
                                <li>
                                    <label>Select Gender</label>
                                    <form:select path="genderId" id="genderId" title="Select Your Gender">
                                    <form:options items = "${gender.genderList}" itemValue="genderId" itemLabel="genderDesc" />
                                    </form:select>
                                    <form:errors path="genderId" class="errors"/>
                                </li>               

                                <li><form:label for="weight" path="weight">Enter Weight <i>(lbs)</i></form:label>
                                    <form:input path="weight" id="weight" title="Enter Weight"/><form:errors path="weight" class="errors"/>
                                </li> 

                                <li><form:label for="height" path="height">Enter Height <i>(feet)</i></form:label>
                                    <form:input path="height" id="height" title="Enter Height"/><form:errors path="height" class="errors"/>
                                </li>
```

Comment: `model.addAllAttributes(Collection)` uses attribute name generation to reference each object in the collection. Since they are all `Citizens` objects, they will each override the previous value with key `citizens` and so only the last one will appear if you try to retrieve it in your view.

Comment: Ok please tell me what is the right approach to be able to navigate through the records from the collection

Comment: I told you yesterday lol, `model.addAttribute("citizens", citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen))`. Then reference the list as `${citizens}` where "citizens" is the key in your request context.

Comment: yes i remember you said that however if i include a next record button on the form how do i move to the next record in the list. I want to be able to move to the next record form the model and not in the view. Yesterday you said place an index on the field however i am using spring form tags which automatically binds the object to the fields. So i need to go to the record in the model and then return it to the view.

Comment: You're going to need to use some combination of javascript/ajax and form submission to achieve pagination.

Comment: any examples on how pagination can be implemented in Spring MVC

Comment: Google java web pagination, eg. http://blog.fawnanddoug.com/2012/05/pagination-with-spring-mvc-spring-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...
In controller

```
model.addAttribute("citizens",citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen));
```

Now in your jsp do this:
1. Add this at top of jsp page
 
 `<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` 
2. Now add this code in your html body

```
<c:forEach items="${citizens}" var="citizen">
First name:- ${citizen.fName} , Last Name:- ${citizen.lName}
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok this is more like a closer answer however i am using spring form tags so i want to maintain <form:input path="fName" id="fName" title="Enter First Name"/><form:errors path="fName" class="errors"/><label id="fName"></label> is there a way to return the data one at a time into the spring form tags without displaying all the records. The reason i want to do this is i want to user to be able to update the record after they query

Comment: why are you passing a list then?try doing it one at a time. :)

Comment: the query returns many rows when you say return one at a time do you mean restrict it form the database?

Comment: yes..u cn do that..otherwise display all the returned citizens as i mentioned and then provide a link for update each one which will be constructed at runtime. i think this should help you.any how you are not going to do a batch update i guess. So better expose another URL which will be dedicated to updation of each user.

Comment: no i am not doing a batch update just want to update records one at a time. can you tell me how does mysql restrict records based on rownum. For e.g. query will return 5 records however i want to include something in the query that will return one record at a time based on a rownum = 1 or 2 or 3....

Comment: it would be easier for me to do a count of all the records that the query will return so i will have an idea before hand of the total number of records but i would also like to retrieve the records one at a time from mysql but i dont know if there is a way to select .... from table where rownum = 1;

Comment: if you restrict it in the db end how will you get other records?Got it?? So you can better try what i said.. as far as Mysql is concerned check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-top-clause.htm)

Comment: i was going to get the other records based on when the user makes a request select ... from table where ... and rownum = 1, thats the first record. user clicks next record i increment the row number to 2 and select .... from table where .... and rownum = 2 ..... so each request i will get another record and since i am getting a count before hand of total records that match the criteria i will be able to tell the user when they click next record button if the record number is 6 and 5 is the total number of records i can tell the user last record

Comment: isnt der a chance f records getting added by some other user in between the process???